# Navbar with hash link (jQuery mobile)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

How can I add use links with hash the same as links without hashes? (e.g: mySubpage**#test**).

I still want to use the jQuery mobile feautres for naviagion, just having an hash to the link!

Sample (HTML)

```
<div data-role="navbar" data-grid="d">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://orf.at">Google</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://google.com#test">Google with hash (not working)</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[Fidldler](http://fiddle.jshell.net/mNmXf/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Add it like this:

```
 <li><a href="http://google.com#test" rel="external">Google with hash (not working)</a>
```

Basically you need to add **rel="external"** attribute. It is a sign to jQuery Mobile to open this link as an external page.

Official documentation: **[Linking pages](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/pages/page-links.html)**

Comment: Yes, data-ajax="false" would work too. But I want to stay in the mobile application and use all it's features (giving an exeranal link was for fiddler purposes :P)

Comment: You want to load external page into your page content?

Comment: no, the page is still from me, but the link to it contains a hash (generated this way). The loaded page is still fully under my control

Comment: Then If I understood you correctly you want to use link to local page but with # symbol in link?